# Batch file question: How can I load a text table from a file (with exclamation marks) into a global array?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, batch-file, global-variables, delayedvariableexpansion

My goal is to load a text file into a global array, and the file contains exclamation marks. I want to then bubble sort the array, and save the contents to a new file. Unfortunately I cannot even get past loading data into an array. I tried using for loops, but it seems delayed expansion is both needed and not needed. Of course, any variables made inside the loops are local variables due to the setlocal command, correct? So once endlocal is reached (in order to toggle delayed expansion), the scope is gone. I was thinking that I need the array to be global so that I can continue manipulating it later on. (I tried to add set commands at the end of endlocal to pass the local values up to higher scope, but my attempts got me nowhere.)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
set "file=list.txt"

echo Extracting titles and IDs...

for /f "usebackq delims=; tokens=1,2* skip=1" %%a in ("%file%") do (
    set /a count+=1
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    set "title=%%b"
    set "gameid=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=- tokens=1,2*" %%x in ("!gameid!") do (
        echo %%y %%x "!title!"
        set "entry[!count!]=%%y %%x !title!"
    echo %count% - !count!
    )
    endlocal
    endlocal
)


pause
```

The input file looks like:

```
ID;Title;Other;Headings;We;Dont;Need
ABC-456;My second game ever! Even better!;foo;bar;blah;blah;blah
XYZ-123;My first game ever! Yes!;foo;bar;blah;blah;blah
```

My end goal is to create a file in the form

```
123 XYZ "My first game ever! Yes!"
456 ABC "My second game ever! Even better!"
```

after sorting by the numerical values. If anyone could help just get through the first part (loading data into an array), that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you just try using %%a and %%b?  `for /f "delims=- tokens=1,2*" %%x in ("%%a") do ( echo %%y %%x "%%b" ...` etc.

Comment: @avery_larry I'm not sure what you mean. The contents of %%a and %%b will depend on whether delayed expansion is set, and %%a needs to be parsed into two parts (the second of which is what determine the sort order). How do you propose using just %%a and %%b to build a global array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid delayed expansion completely by not using variables, when you can use `for` variables.

The only spot that would require delayed expansion, can be done by an alternative:

```
call set "entry[%%count%%]=%%Y %%X %%B"
```

`call` forces another layer of expansion. for that to work properly, you have to make sure, `%%var%%` doesn't get confused with `%%v` and `ar%%`. That's the reason, I changed the `for` variable to uppercase (`%%a` is different from `%%A`).

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
set "file=list.txt"

echo Extracting titles and IDs...
for /f "usebackq delims=; tokens=1,2* skip=1" %%A in ("%file%") do (
    set /a count+=1
    for /f "delims=- tokens=1,2*" %%X in ("%%A") do (
        call set "entry[%%count%%]=%%Y %%X %%B"
    )
)
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('set entry[') do @echo %%B)|sort
pause
```

(Note: the sorting works only, when all the items have a three-digit number)

Output with your example data:

```
Extracting titles and IDs...
123 XYZ My first game ever! Yes!
456 ABC My second game ever! Even better!
```